# How do you remove an element from an array based on element's field value? (Spring-Boot, Reactive MongoDB)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive

I have a Room object. It is essentially a DTO. It has a List or MongoDB an array of User Objects.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to remove a user from the array based on the user's id and couple other things (roomId, roomLeaderId).

```
public Mono<RoomData> findAndTryKickUser(String roomId, String requestUserId,
        String kickUserId){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(roomId).and("roomLeaderId").is(requestUserId)
            .and("userRoomDatas").elemMatch(Criteria.where("userId").is(kickUserId)));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("userRoomDatas.$.userId", kickUserId);
    FindAndModifyOptions options = FindAndModifyOptions.options();
    options.returnNew(true);
    return template.findAndModify(query, update, options, RoomData.class);
}
```

Now I do have the option to make a User object and place the id in and try to remove the user that way (I haven't tried it yet, but I think that would work), but from my understanding of the placeholder "$" I should be able to remove element.

```
{"_id":"5b45572047f84e3d10c59b8a"
,"userRoomDatas":[{"isInGame":false,"isReady":true,"isSpectator":false,"userId":"5b45572047f84e3d10c59b84"}]
,"selectedScreen":"MATCHMAKING"
,"privacySetting":"PUBLIC"
,"roomLeaderId":"5b45572047f84e3d10c59b84"
,"botHostId":"5b45572047f84e3d10c59b84"
,"matchmakingData":   {"selectedQueId":"5b45572047f84e3d10c59b85","matchmakingRating":"M3"}
,"currentRoomStatus":"IN_ROOM"
,"canStartSearch":false
,"password":"AA=="
,"quickJoinEnabled":true
,"roomRating":"MEMERS_ONLY"
,"_class":"room"}
```

EDIT: I made some edits to the code. In part of experimenting with unset but I realized id is actually userId for UserRoomData. Still erroring out in my JUnit tests.

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 2: 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value", "code" : 2, "codeName" : "BadValue" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException:

Comment: Can you show us a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: @Veeram I can. I changed somethings in this post to make it simpler but  I'll re-edit my post to reflect my actually code (I just changed variable names).

Comment: I'll also try to format the document for this SOF post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$pull is array operator and takes the query to match and delete the matching rows in embedded array.

Something like

```
 public Mono<RoomData> findAndTryKickUser(String roomId, String requestUserId, String kickUserId){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(roomId).and("roomLeaderId").is(requestUserId)
            .and("userRoomDatas").elemMatch(Criteria.where("userId").is(kickUserId)));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("userRoomDatas", new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(kickUserId)));
    FindAndModifyOptions options = FindAndModifyOptions.options();
    options.returnNew(true);
    return template.findAndModify(query, update, options, RoomData.class);
}
```

Reference

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents

Comment: Yup it worked. I had no idea you could add Query object to the pull method. Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot @Veeram.